# Why does my hash map code print null?

Tags: java, null, hashmap

I have the following code and I want to print `x`, `y`, and `z`.  When I do that, I expect `(1969, 21, 7)`, `(1969, 4, 12)`, and `(1969, 21, 7)` respectively.  Instead, I get `null` `null` `null`.

My question is, why does the code below print null for x, y, and z instead of the actual date?

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class GregorianCalenderTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        HashMap st = new HashMap();

        GregorianCalendar x = new GregorianCalendar(1969, 21, 7);
        GregorianCalendar y = new GregorianCalendar(1969, 4, 12);
        GregorianCalendar z = new GregorianCalendar(1969, 21, 7);

        st.put(x,  "human in space");
        x.set(1969, 4, 12);

        System.out.println(st.get(x));
        System.out.println(st.get(y));
        System.out.println(st.get(z));


    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here: `x.set(1969, 4, 12);` you change already defined object **after** putting into `Map`.

Never change internal values of an object which is used for `Map` key. It brakes `hashCode()` value, `equals()` method, and after that your map can be thrown out to the dustbin.

Comment: So even when printing `y` and `z` those values become null at that point too?

Comment: What are you doing is dangerous. Furthermore, you map contains only one key-value pair, why do you expect see here 3 not-null values?